# What could possibly explain that Windows 10 silently added ZIP files to ZIP files before, but not now?

Tags: windows-10, zip, drag-and-drop

The other day, I felt a cold sensation down my back after realizing that some ZIP archives that I had in a directory contained other ZIP archives, which I remember having tried to move to that same dir. It turned out, in my testing, that I was able to drag and drop files (including other archives) into ZIP files and they were automatically *added* to the archive, without any confirmation, rather than putting them in the same dir. (I use File Explorer.)

However, prior to asking this question here, I of course wanted to verify this. When I tested it now, on both my main Windows 10 OS and in my VM (also running Windows 10, but a different version), I could not replicate this. It did not at all behave like this.

I can only see three possible explanations:

1. I did something different that time, or now, but what?
2. Microsoft has updated Windows 10 in the last few days to fix this "error" (seems like it would be seen as a feature).
3. I have gone crazy and hallucinated it all.

I swear that it added files to the archives, silently, without asking, if you dragged and dropped a file into the file name or close to the file name. Now it moves the file to that dir instead.

Although I'm glad that this is not normal behaviour, I'm confused as to why I experienced it the other day, and what could possibly explain this. I'm 99% sure that I didn't hold down some keyboard key or anything which would possibly trigger an "alternate mode" or something.

Answer (score 0):

Zip files can show up as a directory in the explorer tree. Chances are you accidentally dragged one item further down and into the zip file rather than the directory.

Often the directory tree expands as you drag into it and zip files appear in that tree as if they are directories. If the tree expanded to show the zip file just as you released the mouse button it could have expanded so that the zip file was under the mouse as you released.

It's not really a bug, but a slightly annoying feature.